# AWS Lambda Hanging Indefinitely when making thumbnails of jpg files

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, python-imaging-library, aws-lambda

I had followed [this example](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html) and altered it slightly, but had it working very well for a long time now. I had been using exclusively PNG files as input, and everything had been working.  I have recently tried to switch to use JPG images (due to some limitations of PNG images as far as vert/horizontal orientation) as input, and I have tested the lambda function from the AWS CLI `invoke` and it works.

When I try to upload the same test file from the website (jpg), the s3 request hangs indefinitely, leaving the client spinning with no response from s3.  I can see the **original file is uploaded to the main bucket successfully**, but the thumbnails are never created, and **no record is ever logged in the CloudWatch Log**.  Again, testing using the `invoke` function returns code 202 and successfully creates the thumbnails.  SO I am really at a loss.

Also everything works fine when using PNG files, so it seems to be something with jpg support.  I had assumed it was that i had installed PIL without jpeg support but I have debugged that and tested with jpg images using the installed lambda function and AWS `invoke`.  It drives me crazy because all the tests work, just in production the request "dies silently" leaving me unable to troubleshoot.

Here is the lambda function:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import boto3
import os
import sys
import uuid
from PIL import Image
import PIL.Image

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

def resize_image(image_path, resized_path, resized_width):
    with Image.open(image_path) as image:
        if image.size[0] > resized_width:
            image.thumbnail((resized_width, image.size[1]/(image.size[0]/resized_width)))
        image.save(resized_path)

def handler(event, context):
    for record in event['Records']:
        bucket = record['s3']['bucket']['name']
        key = record['s3']['object']['key']
        download_path = '/tmp/{}{}'.format(uuid.uuid4(), key)
        upload_path_small = '/tmp/resized_small-{}'.format(key)
        upload_path_medium = '/tmp/resized_medium-{}'.format(key)

        s3_client.download_file(bucket, key, download_path)
        resize_image(download_path, upload_path_small, 600)
        resize_image(download_path, upload_path_medium, 1200)
        s3_client.upload_file(upload_path_small, '{}small'.format(bucket), key)
        s3_client.upload_file(upload_path_medium, '{}medium'.format(bucket), key)
```

Anyways I understand that this question is going to be difficult for anyone out there to troubleshoot for me, but if anyone has any suggestions that would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

**UPDATE**

So while the request was hanging there in the browser, I edited the input of the manual `invoke` function from the AWS CLI to the name of the newly uploaded jpg main image, and that created the thumbnails and then the web request in the browser suddenly completed and responded.  Such a strange issue.

**CLOSURE**

For all of you who were nice enough to read this entire post, I have identified the problem, just as John Rotenstein recommended in his comment, I checked the S3 event which triggers the Lambda function, which I had kind of forget about.  I had originally set it only to trigger for png files.  So that was the entire problem right there.  Explains why there was no log in CloudWatch.

Comment: The first thing to confirm is whether Amazon S3 is correctly triggering the Lambda function. If so, you should see it shown in the Monitoring tab of the Lambda console and in CloudWatch Logs. If they do not shown an invocation of the function, then this is where you need to investigate. Check that you have "Enable trigger" for the S3 trigger turned on and that the **Event Type** is `Object Created (All)`.

Comment: Thats it you got it!  I had set up the filter initially to only trigger on `png` files...  Thanks so much.  Should have known that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to confirm is whether Amazon S3 is correctly triggering the Lambda function. If so, you should see it shown in the Monitoring tab of the Lambda console and in CloudWatch Logs.

If they do not shown an invocation of the function, then this is where you need to investigate. Check that you have "Enable trigger" for the S3 trigger turned on and that the **Event Type** is `Object Created (All)`.